# Create Managed Object Model From Existing XSD - iPhone Core Data

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

I have several existing XML schema files with a defined data model. I would now like to incorporate the exact data model in an iPhone app, using Core Data for persistence. Does anyone know if there is a way to create a Managed Object Model other than by using the graphical tool in Xcode? It would take me a long long time to have to go through and re-create my object model in Xcode. It would be nice if I could just somehow import what I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode's graphical tool is the only way to create a model at this time.  You can write code to dynamically create a model in memory but it can't be persisted (the data can but the model cannot).

You can also create the model from your data objects but that takes as long if not longer than using the graphical tool.